# Can I show another commit in a second magit-revision buffer?

Tags: magit

Is there a way to have magit show two commits in two different buffers?

I want to visually look at two commits at the same time. Using `magit-show-commit` opens a magit-revision buffer. Doing another `magit-show-commit` in another buffer or frame or window reuses the original magit-revision buffer and overwrites its contents.

Can I somehow force emacs or magit two open a second independent magit-revision buffer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll have to use <kbd>M-x magit-toggle-buffer-lock</kbd> in the first buffer. This tells Magit to never use it to display "another thing of the same kind from the same repository".

That's a bit strange, I know. Un-emacsy even. But unfortunately Magit has been doing it for a long time. So changing this will be hard, there's a lot of code that assumes things work that way. Also it's not like the current approach doesn't have advantages, we get some features for free, that would otherwise be difficult to implement. But I plan to change this eventually. This is related to the much larger issue [#2985](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2985) (though it is not explicitly mentioned there yet).

Comment: That works fine. I also think it is sufficiently convenient for a rather seldomly used operation. So, no problem for me with this approach. Thanks.